# Como extrair CNPJ do Certificado Digital A1 .pfx ou .p12 no Linux e Windows usando .NET Core?

Tags: c#, docker, asp-net-core

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema onde fazemos o cadastro de empresas por certificado digital, em que o usuário faz o upload do arquivo, coloca a senha e importa.
Eu preciso extrair o CNPJ que está dentro do certificado para consultar os dados da Empresa na Receita Federal e realizar o cadastro.

O sistema tem como finalidade consultar Documentos Fiscais na Sefaz, por isso precisamos do Certificado e dos dados da Empresa.

Em uma máquina Windows (*no meu ambiente de desenvolvimento*), estava usando esse método para extrair o CNPJ e estava dando certo:

```cs
public static string ExtrairCNPJArquivo(X509Certificate2 arquivo)
{
  const string oid = "2.16.76.1.3.3";
  StringBuilder cnpj = new StringBuilder();

  foreach (X509Extension extension in arquivo.Extensions)
  {
    string texto = extension.Format(true);
    string[] linhas = texto.Split(new char[] { '\n', '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    for (int i = 0; i < linhas.Length; i++)
    {
      if (linhas[i].Trim().StartsWith(oid))
      {
        string valores = linhas[i].Substring(linhas[i].IndexOf('=') + 1);
        string[] elementos = valores.Split(' ');

        byte[] cnpjBytes = new byte[14];

        for (int j = 0; j < cnpjBytes.Length; j++)
          cnpjBytes[j] = Convert.ToByte(elementos[j + 2], 16);

        cnpj.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(cnpjBytes));

        break;
      }
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cnpj.ToString()))
      break;
  }

  return cnpj.ToString();
}
```

Mas no meu ambiente de produção, uso uma máquina Linux que roda no Docker, e essa forma usada acima não funciona para essa plataforma.
O texto do `extension.Format(true);` estava vindo como `othername:<unsupported>` e é nesse texto onde vem o CNPJ do Certificado. Então vi que no Linux não funciona dessa forma.

Como posso fazer isso funcionar nas duas plataformas?

Answer (score 0):

Depois de ter procurado bastante e não encontrado uma resposta, fiz dessa forma e funciona para as duas plataformas:

```cs
public static string ExtrairCNPJArquivo(X509Certificate2 certificado)
{
    const string oIdSubjectAlternativeName = "2.5.29.17";

    var extensao = certificado.Extensions[oIdSubjectAlternativeName];
    var texto = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(extensao.RawData);

    var matches = Regex.Matches(texto, @"(?<!\d)\d{14}(?!\d)");
    var cnpjValido = matches.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Value.ValidarCnpj());

    return cnpjValido?.Value;
}
```

Testei na minha máquina local Windows, e também subi no Docker Linux e funcionou dessa forma.

O CNPJ fica dentro do extension SubjectAlternativeName, então vamos direto nessa extension, pegamos o byte, convertemos para string e buscamos o CNPJ usando a regex que trás somente números que tem 14 caracteres.

Cogitamos que poderia ter mais do que um número de 14 caracteres, então para aprimorar, você pode usar o `Regex.Matches`, e validar qual CNPJ está correto, caso dê mais do que um match. Mas isso é um cenário bem difícil de acontecer; deixei dessa forma para que se acontecer um dia, o código já está preparado.

Para validar o CNPJ (*caso queria, também CPF*), veja esse link: https://gist.github.com/rdakar/dba890b5e2cbdeb7c62c0dee9f627a7f

Comment: Muito bom essa resolução